# How to wrap long lines in contenteditable div with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, contenteditable

I want to make my contenteditable div to:

**Wrap the long lines text in it and wrap at end of words.**

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/aisin/aL9fwggc/

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="msg"></div>
    <div class="editor-wrap">
      <div class="editor" contenteditable="true">How can I wrap long lines here?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow the `.right` to shrink, so if you change `flex: 1 0 auto` to `flex-grow: 1` (or `flex: 1 1 auto`) the text will wrap

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#app {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.left {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #B1D27C;
}
.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.msg {
  height: 100px;
  background: #4E8DF4;
}
.editor-wrap {
  flex: 1;
}
.editor {
  background: #FECF45;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="msg"></div>
    <div class="editor-wrap">
      <div class="editor"How can I wrap long lines here?  contenteditable="true">How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Update based on a comment

If you have "Looooooooooooooooooooong" words you need to use `word-break: break-all`

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#app {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.left {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #B1D27C;
}
.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.msg {
  height: 100px;
  background: #4E8DF4;
}
.editor-wrap {
  flex: 1;
}
.editor {
  background: #FECF45;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="msg"></div>
    <div class="editor-wrap">
      <div class="editor"How can I wrap long lines here?  contenteditable="true">How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? How can I wrap long lines here? Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong words </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it in your demo, it works well for wrapping the content after word, but if I enter a long enough word (eg: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...), it still has the problem. So you can read my answer, I tried out a better solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46034770/1776932

Comment: @Aisin For that you need to use `word-break: break-all`, which is the proper way to solve that. Updated my answer with a 2nd sample

Comment: yes, after adding `word-break: break-all`, it works.

Comment: I know its been long, but I just wanted to say "Thank you", you saved me from the hell I was in.

Answer (score 0):

Give width to .editor class:

```
 .editor{
    width:362px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just define width of `.left` or `.right` it will be work fine

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#app {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.left {
  min-width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #B1D27C;
}
.right {
 width:75%;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.msg {
  height: 100px;
  background: #4E8DF4;
}
.editor-wrap {
  flex: 1;
}
.editor {
  background: #FECF45;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="msg"></div>
    <div class="editor-wrap">
      <div class="editor" contenteditable="true">How can I wrap long lines here?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any other solutions? Because `#app` is responsive, the width of `.left` is fixed but `.right` is not. Thank you.

Comment: But we can use width with parentage (%) that is working while responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `width: 1px` in `.right`, which looks like css hack.
In this way, no matter enter some normal words or a long enough word (eg: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...), it will wrap well won't make `.right` overwidth.

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#app {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.left {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #B1D27C;
}
.right {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1px; /* add width */
}
.msg {
  height: 100px;
  background: #4E8DF4;
}
.editor-wrap {
  flex: 1;
}
.editor {
  background: #FECF45;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="msg"></div>
    <div class="editor-wrap">
      <div class="editor" contenteditable="true">How can I wrap long lines here?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By using `width`, you break the Flexbox model and will likely run into other issues later on. I updated my answer with the proper way to deal with long words.

Comment: Thank you...and if you run into more issues with this, drop me note.